# PHP Laravel 5.5 Site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am really new to Laravel and have no experience in using it at all. So, now I am trying to build a site a per the below requirements:

> Create a PHP Laravel Site with the following specs:
>
> Version and Software Requirement:
>
> PHP Laravel Framework 5.5 Mysql Bootstrap
>
> Functional Requirements:
>
> Create a site with a login page. Only authorized users with the
>   correct login and password will be able to access the site. Once,
>   login, the user will be able to do the following:
>   Create/Read/Update/Delete Comments. A page to display all listing of
>   the comments created. *Comment model will be as follow:  author,
>   description, created_at, updated_at*

Edited: I've managed to install Laravel. Now I am facing another problem. When I run `php artisan migrate`, it will gives me the following errors:

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database
 'task' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = task
and table_name = migrations)
```

I have changed the .env file to this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=task
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=null
```

And I have also uncomment the below extension in php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Please help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question. Truthfully, you're not really asking a question, but rather looking for a reference. Also looking at a site will not allow you to understand how it works "under the hood".

I would recommend the *Laravel from Scratch* video series uploaded by Traversy Media on YouTube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EU7PRmCpx-0

I've watched through this video series online and it really allows you to understand how to use all of the tools (artisan especially) Laravel has to offer. It goes in depth past the typical MVC design pattern and generic PHP functionality. It showcases why Laravel is an awesome, elegant and quality framework.

Hope this helps you get a little further and find what you're looking for.

### Edit:

As pointed out in the comments, I really should have mentioned Laracasts. The very best part about Laravel is the amount of information and organized documentation you can find. Laracasts are living proof of that. The instruction is very well organized, constructive and easy to follow / understand.

https://laracasts.com/

Comment: How dare you give him a reference without mentioning laracasts :P

Comment: I thought that about 20 minutes after I wrote this. The best part about Laravel is the documentation, Laracasts included! @SuperKevin

Comment: Hi, I've tried installing Laravel. But when I issued : composer global require "laravel/installer", the terminal will give me this:

    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.1.0 requires php >=5.5.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.8) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Error tells you exactly what the problem is. Update your PHP.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've successfully updated my PHP. Now I am having problem with the 'php artisan migrate'.